# Creating custom html content based on a sql bit value. null, 0, 1

Tags: php, html, sql

If there is no image it returns **No Rx on File**, this works fine. If there is an image it returns **Rx Requires Validation** in a blue link. When an image is uploaded it's a 0, when it's selected as active it becomes a 1 as the active field in the database. I'm not sure how to have all images as 0 blue and now the active images that are 1 green. I thought my logic is quite busted at this point.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if ($a['rx_scanned'] === null)
    {
         echo "<tr><td>**No Rx on File**</td></tr>"; 
    }


elseif ($a['rx_scanned'] = 1 ) 
    {
  $rx_image_color = '#009933';

    echo "<tr><td> &nbsp;<img src='http://sqlserver/test/tim/leaflet/check-icon.gif'>&nbsp;<a href='" 
            . matry::base_to('patient/image/view', array('event_id'=>$event->id, 'patient_id'=>$patient->code, 'uniqueid'=>$a['image_id'])) 
            . "' style='color:$rx_image_color'>Valid Rx on File</a></td></tr>"; 

    }
else   
    { 
      $rx_image_color = '#3366FF';
      echo "<tr><td>" . cbox_return($name) . "<a href='" 
            . matry::base_to('patient/image/view', array('event_id'=>$event->id, 'patient_id'=>$patient->code, 'uniqueid'=>$a['image_id'])) 
            . "'>**Rx Requires Validation**</a></td></tr>"; 
    }   

echo "<tr><td></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you're stating rx_scanned is a boolean value, not a numeric.

You need to change your conditional to check for a boolean (I am not a PHP developer, but I imagine something like so)

```
if ($a['rx_scanned']) {
  $rx_image_color = '#009933';
   // Insert your stuff here.
}
else {
  $rx_image_color = '#3366FF';
  echo "<tr><td>**No Rx on File**</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: I updated my code but i'm still having issues with the last else statement.. any more help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.